# what does NSEE mean? and what's happening in this code?

Tags: java

I was reading the following code, and came across NSEE. What does it mean? what's the following code block trying to demostrate?

```
public static void objectArrayExamples()
{
Dog[] dogList = new Dog[10];
// How many Dog objects now exist?
dogList[5].bark(5); //uh oh! NSEE
for(int i = 0; i < dogList.length; i++)
{
dogList[i] = new Dog();
}
dogList[3].setName(“Bowzer”);
}
```

Comment: `NoSuchElementException`, I'd guess.

Comment: @DanielFischer it's reporting NSEE(or NPE) because the dogList wasn't initialized?

Comment: Well, yes, except that, as Ian Roberts said, you'd get a `NullPointerException` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSEE` stands for `NoSuchElementException`, however the example is wrong, you get a `NullPointerException` there.

What it tries to demonstrate is a good question, my guess is that it tries to demonstrate the difference between initialising the array itself and initialising an element of that array.

The lesson is that `new Dog[10]` doesn't actually create any `Dog` objects, so the answer to the question in the comment is: none. `new Dog[10]` only creates an empty array, 10 elements long, capable of holding `Dog` objects.

Answer (score 4):

From the context I'd guess `NoSuchElementException` but that's not what you'd get in this situation, you'd actually get a `NullPointerException` because in Java a new array of non-primitive type is filled with nulls.

Answer (score 1):

could be [NoSuchElementException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html). you would get NullPointerException in your code here as you never populated your array.

```
dogList[5].bark(5); //uh oh! NSEE
```

Answer (score 0):

You get NPE - `NullPointerException` here because you created array but have not filled it. Your array contains null elements only. When you are trying to access method of element #5 you get NPE because the element is null.

You have to initialize the element first:

`dogList[5] = new Dog();`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just declaring the array as `Dog[] dogList = new Dog[10];`, and not populating the array, its should be giving `NullPointerException` exception on retrieval/usage (`dogList[5].bark(5);`) stating there is no such element.

If you move `dogList[5].bark(5);` down once your array is populated, you should be good e.g below:

```
    Dog[] dogList = new Dog[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < dogList.length; i++)
    {
      dogList[i] = new Dog(); //<- Your array is populated here
    }
    dogList[5].bark(5); //<-- Your statement can be moved here
    dogList[3].setName(“Bowzer”);
```

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchElementException` is an exception from the `Enumeration` API, of which there is no trace in the code you have shown. Perhaps the method `bark` uses this API, but that is impossible to tell from the code you have posted.

Of course, if what you have shown is the literal code where the exception is supposed to happen, then your statement is simply false because that piece of code cannot possibly produce the exception since there is no instance of `Dog` to call the method `bark` on. This code reliably throws a `NullPointerException`.